# Aspose DataSet.readXml producing more complicated structure

Tags: java, xml, dataset, aspose.words

So I was checking the examples for Java, and noticed the example that uses `InTableList.doc` / `InTableList` from https://github.com/aspose-words/Aspose.Words-for-Java/tree/master/Examples/src .

### Aspose Code

They are creating the DataSet manually in the Common.java file.
Small sub-excerpt of the code:

```
// Create a new data set
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("ds");

        // Add a new table to store contracts
        DataTable dtContracts = new DataTable("Contracts");

        // Add a new table to store managers
        DataTable dtManagers = new DataTable("Managers");

        // Add a new table to store clients
        DataTable dtClients = new DataTable("Clients");

        // Add columns to Managers table
        dtManagers.getColumns().add("Id", int.class);
        dtManagers.getColumns().add("Name");
        dtManagers.getColumns().add("Age", int.class);
        dtManagers.getColumns().add("Photo", byte[].class);
        ds.getTables().add(dtManagers);

        // Add columns to Contracts table
        dtContracts.getColumns().add("Id", int.class);
        dtContracts.getColumns().add("ClientId", int.class);
        dtContracts.getColumns().add("ManagerId", int.class);
        dtContracts.getColumns().add("Price", float.class);
        dtContracts.getColumns().add("Date", Date.class);
        ds.getTables().add(dtContracts);

        // Add columns to Clients table
        dtClients.getColumns().add("Id", int.class);
        dtClients.getColumns().add("Name");
        ds.getTables().add(dtClients);
        ds.getRelations().add(dtClients,dtContracts, "Id","ClientId");
        ds.getRelations().add(dtManagers,dtContracts, "Id","ManagerId");
```

And the word template is like this:

```
<<foreach [m in ds.Managers]>><<[m.Name]>>  <<[m.Contracts.sum(
c => c.Price)]>><</foreach>>

Total:  <<[ds.Contracts.
sum(
c => c.Price)]>>
```

This seems quite simple and a root node is not needed.

### My Code

I have the following XML structure:

```
<root>
    <reference>b</reference>
    <caseHandler>
        <fullName>dddd</fullName>
        <active>true</active>
    </caseHandler>
    <name>This is the name of the case</name>
    <deadline>1528220937444</deadline>
    <associated>
        <code>ddd</code>
        <active>true</active>
        <id>-9</id>
        <parentScopeId>-3</parentScopeId>
        <title>ddddddddddd</title>
    </associated>
    <associated>
        <code>ddd</code>
        <active>true</active>
        <id>-9</id>
        <parentScopeId>-3</parentScopeId>
        <title>ddddddddddd</title>
    </associated>
</root>
```

And I am loading the XML into the dataSet like this:

```
DataSet set = new DataSet("ds");
set.readXml(new ByteArrayInputStream(escaped.getBytes()));

log.info("XML " + otherXml);

ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
engine.buildReport(doc, set);//model
```

### Problem

The underlying report insists in everything being under a "ROOT" node.
Obviously, this is the `<root>` xml tag. 
How do I modify my set to get rid of this extra level?

My problem is that I need to encircle all my text in the word file with a 'foreach' that is related to this 'root'.

```
<<foreach [c in root]>> 

<< [c.name] >> << [c.reference] >>

Case Handler : 
<< [c.caseHandler.first().fullName] >>


<<foreach [in c.associated]>>
    (<<[code]>>)    <<[title]>>                     <</foreach>>


 <</foreach>>
```

This is quite annoying...

I would definitely prefer something more simply like this:

```
 << [ds.name] >> << [ds.reference] >>

    Case Handler : 
    << [ds.caseHandler.first().fullName] >>


    <<foreach [in ds.associated]>>
        (<<[code]>>)    <<[title]>>                     <</foreach>>
```

### Question

How do I simplify the structure so that I am able to still read the XML, but I don't need the extra overhead in the word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use ReportingEngine.buildReport as shown below to get the desired output.

Template : <<[ds.name]>> <<[ds.reference]>>

```
DataSet set = new DataSet("ds");
set.readXml(MyDir + "in.xml");

Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "template.docx");
ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
engine.buildReport(doc, set.getTables().get("root").getRows().get(0), "ds");//model

doc.save(MyDir + "output.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to remove `ds` so we access the variables directly? Do we just use: 
`engine.buildReport(doc, set.getTables().get("root").getRows().get(0));`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove ds from 'name' and 'reference' fields. In this case, you need to use ReportingEngine.buildReport (Document, Object[], String[]) method as shown below.

Template : <<[name]>> <<[reference]>>

```
DataSet set = new DataSet("ds");
set.readXml(MyDir + "in.xml");

Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "template.docx");
ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
engine.setOptions(ReportBuildOptions.ALLOW_MISSING_MEMBERS);
engine.buildReport(doc, new Object[]{set.getTables().get("root").getRows().get(0), set}, new String[] {"", "ds"});//model
doc.save(MyDir + "output.docx");
```